# asp.net web forms bind only <%# %>

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

Is here any way of binding `<%# Page.ClientID %>` without binding Page child controls?

For example:

```
<%# SomePageProprtyThatReturnsString %>
<someTag:SomeControl ID="SomeControlID" runat="server" OnDataBinding="SomeControlID_DataBinding"></someTag:SomeControl>
```

If I have following than **SomeControlID** will be bound on each unwanted post-back

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    DataBind();
}
```

If I will not bind page on each post back then **SomePageProprtyThatReturnsString** will not be visible on post-backs

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?  I don't quite understand what the problem is...  You only want SomePageProprtyThatReturnsString  to be evaluated once but show up all the time?  Or SomePageProprtyThatReturnsString  should be within the context of your control?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I not so correctly described my question. We can use instead <%# SomePageProprtyThatReturnsString %> this <%# "some string" %>. So I want to see "some string" on my page always, but SomeControlID shold be bound only if page loaded initially(without post-back)

Comment: As far as I understood <%# %> evaluated only if called Page.DataBind() but If I call this that DataBind() of all page children will be invoked. So I wan't <%# %> to be evaluated each time when page loads, but child control should be bound only if !IsPostBack

Comment: Problem is that I don't know what is <%# %> and how it works so I cannot even google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%# SomePagePropertyThatReturnsString %>
```

Looks like it might be some public property you've created on the `Page` itself? If that is the case you can output that property directly without the need for databinding by changing your code:

```
<%= this.Page.SomePropertyThatReturnsString %>
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. This works fine for me. Could you please explain what is <%# and <%=(I don't know how it called so I can't google any info for that)

Answer (score 3):

You can choose which controls you want to bind. So, if you have something like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSomet Text='<%# SomePageProprtyThatReturnsString %>'/>
<someTag:SomeControl ID="SomeControlID" runat="server" OnDataBinding="SomeControlID_DataBinding"></someTag:SomeControl>
```

You can call `Databind` only on the `Label`:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    lblSomething.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not exactly what I wanted to know. In your scenario I could just put Literal and set it's Text value in OnLoad. Or here is no way to evaluate code within <%# %> on a page without calling DataBind() of Page?

Comment: @Vladimirs No, there isn't. But you can databind the parent control. If you databind an asp:Panel for example all the child controls/expressions are binded

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that you can `DataBind()` other controls than `ListView`s or `Repeater`s - thanks!